# How to send email with phpmailer in phalcon php

Tags: email, gmail, phpmailer, phalcon

Im new in [phalcon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phalcon_%28framework%29) want a working example of [phpmailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) that send email from my site. currently i just figure out like this. i just follow this link: github.com/asyamedya/phalcon-phpmailer.

[config.php]

```
$config = new Phalcon\Config(array(
"app"               => array(
"controllersDir"=> "app/controllers/",
"modelsDir"     => "app/models/",
"viewsDir"      => "app/views/",
"pluginsDir"    => "app/plugins/",
"libraryDir"    => "app/library/",
"helpersDir"    => "app/helpers/",
"formsDir"      => "app/forms/",
"cacheDir"      => "cache/volt/",
"logsDir"       => "cache/logs/",
"encryptKey"    => "",
"baseUri"       => "/demo/",
"StaticBaseUri" => "http://localhost/demo/",
"debug"         =>  '0',
),
"mail"              => array(
    "driver"        => "smtp",
    "host"          => "smtp.gmail.co",                           
    "username"      => "2munax@gmail.com",              
    "password"      => "*****",                           
    "security"      => "tls",   //ssl:465, tls:587                       
    "port"          => 587, 
    "charset"       => "UTF-8",
    "email"         => "2munax@gmail.com",
    "name"          => "webmaster",
),
));
```

[loader.php]

```
use Phalcon\Loader;
$loader = new Loader();
$loader->registerDirs(
    array(
        APP_PATH . $config->app->controllersDir,
        APP_PATH . $config->app->modelsDir,
        APP_PATH . $config->app->pluginsDir,
        APP_PATH . $config->app->libraryDir,
        APP_PATH . $config->app->helpersDir,
        APP_PATH . $config->app->formsDir,
        APP_PATH . $config->app->cacheDir,
    )
)->register();
```

[service.php]

```
use Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault;
use Phalcon\Mvc\View;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Url as UrlResolver;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Router;
use Phalcon\Security;
use \PHPMailer as PHPMailer;
use Phalcon\Mvc\View\Engine\Volt;
use Phalcon\Events\Manager as EventsManager;
use Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql as DbAdapter;
use Phalcon\Flash\Session as FlashSession;
use Phalcon\Logger\Adapter\File as Logger;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Metadata\Apc as ApcMetaData;
use Phalcon\Session\Adapter\Files as SessionAdapter;

    require(APP_PATH . $config->app->libraryDir . 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
    $di->set('pmailer', function() use ($config){
    $pmailer = new PHPMailer();
    //$mail->setLanguage('fr', '/optional/path/to/language/directory/');
    $pmailer->isSMTP(true);
    $pmailer->SMTPDebug = 2;  // Enable verbose debug output
    $pmailer->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
    'verify_peer' => false,
    'verify_peer_name' => false,
    'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
    );
    $pmailer->Charset = $config->mail->charset;
    $pmailer->Host = $config->mail->host;
    $pmailer->SMTPAuth = true;
    $pmailer->Username = $config->mail->username;
    $pmailer->Password = $config->mail->password;
    $pmailer->SMTPSecure = $config->mail->security;
    $pmailer->Port = $config->mail->port;
    $pmailer->addAddress($config->mail->email,$config->mail->name);
    $pmailer->isHTML(true);
    return $pmailer;
});
```

[controller index]

```
public function SendmailAction()
{   
    $this->pmailer->From  = "2munax@gmail.com";
    $this->pmailer->FromName = "user";
    $this->pmailer->addReplyTo("2munax@gmail.com", "user");
    $this->pmailer->addAddress('babymachinery83@gmail.com');   
    $this->pmailer->Subject = "email test !";
    $this->pmailer->Body = "success!";
    $this->pmailer->WordWrap = 70;
    if(!$this->pmailer->send()){echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $this->pmailer->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
    }
}
```

In my library i have this files.

[Library/PHPMailer/]

```
class.phpmailer.php
class.pop3.php
class.smtp.php
PHPMailerAutoload.php
class.phpmaileroauthgoogle.php
```

Comment: [Have you even tried googling this](https://github.com/asyamedya/phalcon-phpmailer)? What have you tried? What kind of errors are you getting?

Comment: You should try something and if you fail, then ask us. StackOverflow is not a service where we write code for you. Please put more effort.

Comment: Niki Mihaylov & Timothy! I updated my question. and unable to send mail. please! tell whats my fault? I'm Getting Fatal error: Class 'Phalcon\PHPMailer' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\app\config\services.php on line 177

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but you I think this is wrong in your service.php

```html
use Phalcon\PHPMailer;
```

Change it to

```html
use \PHPMailer as PHPMailer;
```

Comment: Getting this: Warning: The use statement with non-compound name 'PHPMailer' has no effect in C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\app\config\services.php on line 11

Fatal error: Class 'PHPMailer' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\app\config\services.php on line 177

Comment: Updated, missed the \

Comment: Still same problem! Have anyone here who can give a working example? which also tested.

Comment: You need to show more in your question, something like the composer.json and actual screenshot of the error.

Last try is to use: "use \Email;"

Comment: I have no composer.json file. Also i use \Email all are same result.

Comment: I just change: use \PHPMailer as PHPMailer; instead use \PHPMailer. and now have no error but mail not posting i tested it with if($this->mail->send()){echo('OK');}else{echo('Failed');} this condition.

Comment: Well we are no wizards here at Stackoverflow. We need data in order to figure out the problem. Saying that email is just not sending is definitely not enought. Anyway I see you you Gmail as server, I know for sure that there is some little configuration to be done on youre Gmail account. Google it

Comment: Please! Look my updated Code: now im getting error like: 2016-07-27 07:26:34 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. (0) 2016-07-27 07:26:34 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting.

Comment: Without verbos debug mode it shows like: Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting